# Suppose a signal is growing exponentially. We take its Z transform & find its ROC. So what are we supposed to do practically with the signals in ROC?

Tags: z-transform, transform

Suppose a signal is growing exponentially. We take its Z transform & find its ROC. So what are we supposed to do practically? Are we supposed to manipulate our O/P by multiplying any signal from ROC such that our O/P converges & system is stable? And what if our signal is exponentially decaying so whats the purpose of finding ROC in this case (except for determing stability/casuality)?

Comment: We can't answer this without more context. Why are you looking at the signal and what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: If you refer to this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq_qv3Spzbs&t=461s at 7:00 he takes an unstable O/P of a system & shows that ZT of the unstable system converges in ROC. 
I just want to know what are we supposed to do to our system such that our O/P gets stable?